# Widgets don't adjust width to screenwidth

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm pretty new to Flutter layouts and run into the following issue with this Flutter application (see below).  When I run this (on Linux/desktop) I observe the following:

- when I scale the window vertically, the height of the red containers changes to remain inside the window
- however, when I change the width of the window, the height/width of the containers is not changed and they end up (partly) off-screen

Any ideas why they don't scale in both directions?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Test obviously"),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Row(children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.red)),
                ),
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.red)),
                ),
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.0,
                  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.red)),
                )
              ]))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try with `flex`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Test obviously"),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Row(children: [
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.red)),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.red)),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.red)),
                    )
                  ]))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: glad to help you. Happy coding!